# How to modify a HTML <td> (without any unique properties) element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to modify a  element using JS however this  element does not have any unique properties like ID. Also the table in which this  element resides does not have a unique class. Also, the HTML page has multiple tables and td elements.

**For example**:

Existing HTML :

```
<table border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Id</td>
   <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>12334567</td>
   <td>BirthName</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to modify the cell which contains the value "BirthName" to "BirthName (Sidharth)"

Something Like this:

```
<table border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Id</td>
   <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>12334567</td>
   <td>BirthName (Sidharth)</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is *BirthName* present in multiple tables?

Comment: is BirthName is unique

Comment: You can use Xpath and change it check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do checking the text for all td and change where matches birthname

```
let element = document.querySelectorAll('td');
for(let i = 0; i<element.length; i++){
    if(element[i].innerText == 'BirthName'){
    element[i].innerText += '(Sidharth)';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all  having BirthName by using bellow colde

```
const allTds = document.querySelectorAll('td')

// Find the td element that contains the text "BirthName"
const birthDateTd = Array.from(allTds).filter(td=>td.textContent==='BirthName')
```

After that you can target that `<td>` as you want.

Comment: Would be good to check `innerText` in addition to `textContent`.

Comment: If you want to apply the changes on multiple instances you could replace `.find(td.textContent==='BirthName')` with `.filter(td=>td.textContent==='BirthName')`. This would return an array of DOM elements. I am slow at typing. While I was writing this, Gaurav already updated his post. :D

Comment: I don't thing so But  according to question they don't have any ID or Class.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is unique then you can use Xpath as shown below and change it.

```js
var td = document.evaluate("//td[contains(text(), 'BirthName')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

var thisTd = td.iterateNext();
thisTd.innerHTML = "BirthName (Sidharth)";
```

```html
<table border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Id</td>
   <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>12334567</td>
   <td>BirthName</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```